# Subsetting the first 4 rows of each dataframe in a list

Tags: r, list, dataframe, subset, cbind

I have two lists of dataframes I want to merge however they have different numbers of rows and so I want to take the first four rows of each dataframe in the list so I am able to merge them.

I have tried several things and had not much hope so any help would be appreciated.

This is an example of what I would like:

```
hitID    Data    Time                   hitID     Data      Time
1        A        2                     1         A         2
2        B        3                     2         B         3
3        C        4                     3         C         4
4        D        5
```

Thank you for your help, this is my data each list looks a little like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YNgk7.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SSCou.png)
As you can see there are some dataframes with only 4 rows. My aim is to get the data cbinded so that I have the data for one persons name for the driver followed on the same row by the data for the same persons name for the irons. This would mean I end up with a list of dataframes similar to the one above however with twice as many column from which I can select the important data from. I do not mind if this means loosing the 5th row or not.

Comment: Could you provide further data? I suspect what you asking is not what you need.

Comment: I have a list of dataframes which some are 4 rows and some are 5 rows I need to cut all the 5th rows so that there's 4 rows in each dataframe in a list.

Comment: So, I'm thinking I could save the first 4 rows of each dataframe into a new list

Comment: Is the 5th row really expendable?

Comment: My aim at first was to keep them but I need to be able to combine these lists and so I have settled for getting rid of it so yes

Comment: Say you have a common variable in both lists (like people names). You don't need same sized lists to merge, you can join them by it's key (names). That would also handle ordering issues. That's why i asked for a glimpse of your data.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I have added some pictures and details to the question I think might answer your questions

Answer (score 1):

You may use `Reduce` to apply `merge` on the subsetted data frames in the list.

```
Reduce(function(...) merge(..., all=TRUE), lapply(l, function(x) x[1:4, ]))
#    X1 X2 X3
# 1   1  1  1
# 2   1  1  1
# 3   1  1  1
# 4   1  1  1
# 5   2  2  2
# 6   2  2  2
# 7   2  2  2
# 8   2  2  2
# 9   3  3  3
# 10  3  3  3
# 11  3  3  3
# 12  3  3  3
```

---

*Data:*

```
dat1 <- data.frame(matrix(1, 6, 3))
dat2 <- data.frame(matrix(2, 4, 3))
dat3 <- data.frame(matrix(3, 5, 3))

l <- list(dat1, dat2, dat3)
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `Map` to loop over the two `list`s, get the first 4 rows with `head` of each dataset in the `list`s, and do a `merge`

```
Map(function(dat1, dat2) merge(head(dat1, 4), head(dat2, 4), 
        by = c('hitID')), lst1, lst2)
```

---

If there is only a single `list`, an approach with `tidyverse` would be

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
map(lst1, ~ .x %>%
               slice(1:4)) %>%
         reduce(full_join, by = 'hitID')
```

Comment: Thank you for this, can I ask what should be in place of the lst1 and lst2

Comment: @NatashaJones when I read your description, it says `have two lists of dataframes`.  Here, `lst1`, `lst2` are the names of the list objects

Comment: Oh okay so my bad if my list names are in lst what is in the dat1 and dat2 palce

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to see your data 'cause print quality, so i'm creating some data and you tell if it helps:

```r
library(dplyr)

# Creating data
Ages = data.frame(names = c("John",
                            "Claire",
                            "Steve",
                            "Pete"),
                  Age = c(31, 25, 17, 42))

Jobs = data.frame(names = c("Harry",
                            "Thomas",
                            "Steve",
                            "Pete",
                            "John",
                            "Claire"),
                  job = c("Economist",
                          "Lawyer",
                          "Driver",
                          "Salesman",
                          "Banking",
                          "Physician"))

# Resulting data frame
Ages
#>    names Age
#> 1   John  31
#> 2 Claire  25
#> 3  Steve  17
#> 4   Pete  42
Jobs
#>    names       job
#> 1  Harry Economist
#> 2 Thomas    Lawyer
#> 3  Steve    Driver
#> 4   Pete  Salesman
#> 5   John   Banking
#> 6 Claire Physician

# Merge only lines that are present in both data frames
data = Ages %>% inner_join(Jobs, by = c("names" = "names"))

data
#>    names Age       job
#> 1   John  31   Banking
#> 2 Claire  25 Physician
#> 3  Steve  17    Driver
#> 4   Pete  42  Salesman

# Keep all lines in Job data frame and merge ones found in Ages data frame
data = Ages %>% right_join(Jobs, by = c("names" = "names"))

data
#>    names Age       job
#> 1   John  31   Banking
#> 2 Claire  25 Physician
#> 3  Steve  17    Driver
#> 4   Pete  42  Salesman
#> 5  Harry  NA Economist
#> 6 Thomas  NA    Lawyer
```

<sup>Created on 2020-06-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>